# How do I import other functions in same module directory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made my python module which `A.py` uses `B.py` like below. In such a case, how do I import `B.py` in `A.py`? I want to use `mylib` module from other directory. But my code doesn't work because of path problem.

```
├── main.py
└── mylib
    ├── A.py
    ├── B.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── main_in_mylib.py
```

**A.py**

```
import B
def test():
    B.hello()
```

**B.py**

```
def hello():
    print("hello from B")
```

**main_in_mylib.py**

```
import A
A.test()
```

**main.py**

```
import mylib.A as A
A.test()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mylib.A as A
  File "/home/jef/python-module/mylib/A.py", line 3, in <module>
    import B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

### Updated

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'**

```
# main.py
from mylib.A import test
test()
```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'**

```
# main.py
import mylib.B as B
import mylib.A as A
A.test()
```

Comment: The [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) system in python is not always intuitive, but I think the link here will help you understand how things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change **A** to

```
import mylib.B as B
def test():
    B.hello()
```

instead of

```
import B
def test():
    B.hello()
```

because imports are always relative to the script you call (in this case main.py)

Comment: This is not still clear. Could you check my updates? This may is not correct answer.

Comment: you need to do this import in A

Comment: Thank you. Now my code is working. By the way, is it common way to import other functions in a such situation?

Comment: why not `from mylib import B`? aliasing seems to be redundant here

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I just wanted to keep with the style used in the original question

Answer (score 2):

For the record it is also possible here to do a relative import in `A.py`:

```
from . import B
```

Comment: It looks useful because I don't need to set specific directory name.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you imported a file and trying to call methods using dot notation.

use `from mylib.A import test`

now you can directly use `test()` inside your main.py

in python3 you don't even have to write `__init__.py` inside a directory to tell that it is a package (it is a good practice though)

Comment: Correction.. U can write from A import test